# Como ocupar el 100% de la pagina cuando la tabla muestra 10 datos

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap

tengo la duda de como hacer para que el background de la barra lateral izquierda me ocupe toda la altura de la pantalla y se siga mostrando cuando la tabla me muestre los 100 datos que tenga, no he podido logralo, si alguien me puede ayudar, le agradezco.
se utiliza angular, bootstrap, css, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CSS

```
.menu-navegacion {
  background-color: #00993E !important;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  max-width: 120px;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  height: 100vh !important ;
}
```

HTML

[image: Parte del html de la barra de navegación]

Comment: ¿Probaste usar en lugar de `100vh` algo cómo `100%` ? Otra cosa que puedes probar es en lugar de poner `height` usar `min-height: 100vh;`?

Comment: Pon todo el código en formato texto. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia la imagen del `html` por texto.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez si, ya probé con 100% y tampoco funciona.

Comment: @MauricioContreras no me deja, me sale un error que no me deja guardar la pregunta

Comment: ¿@CristianSilva y cambiándolo por  `min-height: 100vh !important;`?

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez al menos con el min-height mejora, ocupando toda la altura, pero si a la tabla le diho me muestre 100 items, se corta.

Answer (score 0):

a **.menu-navegacion** agregale la **propiedad css** `position: fixed;` para que no ocupe espacio real sobre los otros elementos y que al hacer scroll se mantenga visible en el viewport

`top: 0; left: 0;` para indicarle la **posicion en el viewport** y `heigth: 100vh;` para que ocupe todo el **largo del viewport**,

`un overflow: auto;` por si tienes muchos elementos el aside tenga su propia barra de scroll

y por ultimo tendras el problema de que el contenido del **body** se quedara bajo tu **aside**, por lo que debes aplicar un `padding-left: (tamaño de tu aside);` para solucionarlo.